# bblsty error - not correct

Tags: pdftex, winedt, bbl

I'm trying to complie my old thesis. However I get an error.
How do I fix it?

---

```
\documentclass[14pt]{book}
\topmargin 2mm
\oddsidemargin 10mm
\evensidemargin 10mm
\textwidth 150mm
\textheight 220mm

\usepackage[latin2]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{/usr/TeX/texmf/tex/csplain/czech}
\usepackage{czech}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{a4}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{theorem}

\makeindex

\input{def.tex}

\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\roman{enumi}}


\begin{document}

\title{
1Práce je zaměřena na koncepty řeąení her \\
$n$ hráčů ve tvaru charakteristické funkce \\
{\bf stabilní konfigurace}, {\bf kernel} a {\bf nukleolus}.}

%\maketitle
%\tableofcontents

\input{thU.tex}
\input{th0.tex}
\input{th1.tex}
\input{th2.tex}
\input{th3.tex}
\input{th4.tex}


\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{all}

%\printindex

\end{document}
```

---

**THE ERROR**

```
Command Line:   bibtex.exe "all"
Startup Folder: D:\OldPlocha2\DD\Linux Backup\hda1\home\puf\aha\tex\dip\NOW

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.7050 64-bit)
The top-level auxiliary file: all.aux
The style file: alpha.bst
Database file #1: all.bib
Warning--there's a number but no volume in Chandbook
(There was 1 warning)


Command Line:   makeindex.exe "all.idx"
Startup Folder: D:\OldPlocha2\DD\Linux Backup\hda1\home\puf\aha\tex\dip\NOW

This is makeindex, version 2.15 [MiKTeX 2.9.7050 64-bit] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning input file all.idx....done (7 entries accepted, 0 rejected).
Sorting entries....done (25 comparisons).
Generating output file all.ind....done (20 lines written, 0 warnings).
Output written in all.ind.
Transcript written in all.ilg.


Command Line:   pdflatex.exe --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "all.tex"
Startup Folder: D:\OldPlocha2\DD\Linux Backup\hda1\home\puf\aha\tex\dip\NOW

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7050 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(all.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/base\book.cls
Document Class: book 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/base\bk12.clo))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/base\inputenc.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/base\latin2.def)) (czech.sty

! Package babel Error: You have used an old interface to call babel
(babel)                You may expect compatibility problems wit other packages
.

See the babel package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.74     \bblstyerror

? 

! Emergency stop.
 ...                                              

l.74     \bblstyerror



_____________________________________________________________________

 PDFTeXify Compilation Report (Pages: 0)

 Errors: 2   Warnings: 0   Bad Boxes: 0
_____________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Replace `\usepackage{czech}` by `\usepackage[czech]{babel}` and try again.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It gives no [outpuit pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/515544/no-output-pages-from-pdflatex)